# How do I open a json file using javascript d3?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I'm trying to extract elements from a JSON file using javascript, however I'm getting an error saying it can not load the JSON file.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>D3 Tutorial</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        d3.json("mydata.json", function(data) {

            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)

            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10;})
                    .attr("height", 48)
                    .attr("y", function (d,i) { return i * 50; })
                    .attr("fill", "blue");

        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error the console is spitting out:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/locationoffile..../mydata.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. d3.v3.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null d3.v3.min.js:3
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 d3.v3.min.js:1
```

Comment: For security reasons, on Chrome and Opera you cannot use XMLHttpRequest to load local files. You must run it on a web server. So follow @Quentin's advice and install a server or something. I usually use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for a simple server.

Comment: Or for starters one could go for Apache server. It is easy to understand and nice to implement.Just paste in the htdocs and run the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

d3.json is meant to load data through HTTP. As @Quentin said, you can set up a local server to serve the data over HTTP.

For development like this I use firefox, it seems to be more permissive when it comes to local cross origin requests than chrome. Alternatively you can use http://tributary.io/

Example with your code: http://tributary.io/inlet/5776228

Answer (score 1):

> Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Load the site over HTTP. Install a web server (such as Apache HTTPD or Lighttpd) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to installing web server or using 3rd party online environments you can just use different code editor - [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). It offers feature called "Live Preview". I just hit same error `Uncaught XMLHttpRequest` with similar code, can confirm code works perfectly in Brackets.

*Brackets works directly with your browser to push code edits instantly, so your browser preview is always up to date while you're coding — no page reloads needed. In order to keep your current web browsing unaffected, Brackets Live Preview opens an additional copy of Chrome using a separate Chrome profile.* // From [How to Use Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets)